# Insert mocked object in call hierarchy

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am writing my first unit test (using Mockito). The functionality I wish to test is structured as follows:

```
class ClassA {
    public ClassB b;

    public void methodA() {
        // calls a method of ClassB
        b.methodB();
    }
}

class ClassB {
    public ClassC c;

    public void methodB() {
        // calls a method of ClassC
        someVariable = c.methodC();
    }
}

class ClassC {

    public Object methodC() {
        // do something
        // this method needs to be mocked for testing (needs to return dummy values to ClassB)
    }
}
```

What I really wish to test is whether or not a certain functionality I introduced in `ClassB` still works or not. For that, I need `methodC()` (being called from `ClassB`) to return certain values, hence I mocked `ClassC`.

My problem is that none of the tutorials that I came across show the class under testing being invoked from a different class (like in my case - `ClassB` invoked from `ClassA`).

Also, tutorials show an instance of the class under test being mocked, unlike in my case (I am testing `ClassB` but need to mock `ClassC`).

How should I proceed to write a unit test for `ClassB`? My idea of this unit test looks like the following:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class TestB {

    public ClassA instanceA;

    public ClassB instanceB;

    @Mock
    public ClassC instanceC;        

    public void setUp() {
        // do setup stuff
        when(instanceC.methodC()).thenReturn(dummyValue);
        b.setC(instanceC);
    }

    @Test
    public void Test() {

    }
}
```

I haven't tried this yet, but I'd like to know if this approach seems reasonable, or if my unit test is modeled wrongly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that none of the tutorials that I came across show the class under testing being invoked from a different class

You should not worry about that. When you are testing `ClassB`, you need not think about its callers. Your only goal at this point is to test the functionalities of `ClassB` and nothing else.

Hence, you can remove `public ClassA instanceA;` from your `TestB` class. Your `setUp` method looks fine.

Here's how your test method might look

```
@Test
public void test_methodB() {
    instanceB.methodB();
    //Rest depends on the logic within methodB. Maybe use Mockito verify to verify certain calls were made, use Answers etc.
}
```

> Also, tutorials show an instance of the class under test being mocked

I don't understand why would one need to mock the system under test.

Comment: Thanks. How then, will `ClassB.methodB()` be called (since it is supposed to be called by an instance of `ClassA`)?

Comment: `ClassB` getting called by `ClassA` is only your domain logic. When you are unit testing `ClassB`, you shouldn't think from that standpoint. You are *testing* `ClassB` (ClassB's public methods) directly

Comment: Similarly when you test `ClassA`, you can *mock* `ClassB`

Answer (score 0):

As user7 has mentioned, you should never mock the class under test. Mocking should be used to mock the dependent classes so that you don't have to have to create the dependent class (lets say it takes 3 arguments in its constructor and each argument needs further argument to construct them; to avoid this, we use mock). Instead of creating a dependent class instance, you mock it, and set the expected behavior (using `when(mockedObject.someMethod()).return(dummyValue)`) and only test your class. If the dependent class behaves as it should, does my class behave as I expect it to? So, your setUp method is correct. You set the expectation from ClassC and you are going to test your ClassB.

Answer (score 0):

Just going to order a bit what @user7 is saying to make a little easier.

1. You should have 3 Test Clases (ClassATest, ClassBTest, ClassCTest)
2. In ClassATest you should Mock The instance of classB being used and make sure that methodB is being called on instaceA.methodA() (you can look up Mockito.verify for this)
3. In ClassBTest you should Mock The instance of classC being used and make sure that methodC is being called on instaceB.methodB() (same as before, also look at the InjectMocks annotation)

   ```
   @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
   class TestB {

     @InjectMocks
     public ClassB instanceB;

     @Mock
     public ClassC instanceC;        

     public void setUp() {
       // do setup stuff
       when(instanceC.methodC()).thenReturn(dummyValue);
     }

     @Test
     public void Test() {
       instaceB.methodB();
     }
   }
   ```
4. In ClassCTest you should test all the logic on methodC.